# How to access DOM in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a speedometer in reactJS and using a little vanilla syntax, however canvas is returning null. If I run

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('dial__container');
```

in the console the div pops right up.

Is this merely a timing issue where the canvas hasn't yet rendered or some weird React behavior?

```
import React from 'react';

const canvas = document.getElementById('dial__container');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const radius = canvas.height / 2;

const Speedometer = (props: any) => {

 console.log(canvas); // null
 return (
       <div className="dial__wrapper">
          <canvas id="dial__container" width="150" height="150" />
       </div>
    );
 };

export default Speedometer;
```

Comment: you are trying to get it before it actually exists. It is like `alert(a); a = 2`

Comment: That's what I trying to fix. Normally I could use .onLoad() but that's not applicable. Is there a way to delay the declaration of the variables until the canvas has rendered?

Comment: @AustinCallaghan One way would be to create it as a state and use `componentDidMount()` lifecycle?

Comment: I threw it in a component did mount and that solved the current issue. I'm just curious if theres a better way now. (PS, Thanks for your help)

Comment: @AustinCallaghan Happy to help. I have edited the title for your preference. But just to share an advice, You should read about state in general (not just state in react). Helps you a lot to figure out what things should be in state and what things shouldn't not.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get a node that has not been rendered yet.

You could use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method by converting your component to a state**ful** (class component) one before trying to get your canvas. But keep in mind that this is considered really bad practice and should never be necessary :

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('dial__container');
}
```

Another solution would imply using `refs`, as linked in the other answer, which are also considered a bad practice.

Comment: *you mean by converting your component to a stateful component. You have currently used the word stateless. Functions are stateless, classes are stateful component.

Comment: Woops, edited it

Comment: I think using the `ref` attribute is the only option to access context of the canvas and therefore isn't a bad practise.

Comment: Well, it is the only option to a problem that should never happen, as you should not really need to access an element's context except in extremely rare cases. In those cases, you should use them, but also try not to : https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Comment: See, that's what I've read is that refs are only for rare cases. If I use refs here there will probably be a lot of them and that seems janky.

Comment: If you want to stick to function components (which seems to be the recommended way), then you can use the 'useEffect' hook. This will be run every time a component is rendered and is the function component equivalent of 'componentDidMount'. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're trying to access the element before it appears in the DOM (try to `console.log(document.body.innerHTML)` right under the React import and check what does the DOM look like at the time of calling the `getElemenetById` function.

If you need the element's reference you should use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Is there any reason I should use a ref as apposed to vanilla js methods?

Comment: Check the update.